# Binary code over $F_8$

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, coding-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1$ be irreducible polynomial factor of $x^7 - 1$. I want to prove the following

1. $f$ as exactly three roots in $\mathbb{F}_8^*$
2. let $a$ be some root of $f$, then $\forall g \in \mathbb{F}_2[x] : g(a) = 0$ implies $f \mid g$
3. The code generated by $f$ is $[7,4,3]_2$ code.

---

So far, I have the following partial thoughts:

2. since $f$ is irreducible, it's also must be the minimum polynomial of $a$, otherwise it wasn't irreducible. Thus, it must be $f \mid g$

But regarding (1), (3) i have no idea, so any help will be appreciate!

Comment: How much of the theory of cyclic codes has been covered? For example, do you know how to get a generator matrix and a parity check matrix for this code? Or, have you even covered the BCH-bound?

Comment: Oh, and part 1) is basic (from Galois theory) the other roots are $a^2$ and $a^4$, do you see why?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Im not familiar with BCH Bound, but I do know the generating matrix and PCM form of cyclic codes. Regarding (1) - it follows since $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$, is that your intention?

Comment: Correct. That is how I would have done it.  You can use a parity check matrix to prove that the minimum distance is at least three. This is the case if there are no columns of all zeros (hence no weight $1$ words), and all the columns are distinct (hence no weight $2$ words). Have you seen that result? If not, then my answer gives a totally different way of proving the same thing.

Comment: Yes I did, but how can you tell the PCM has distict columns? Or only by constucting it explicitly and examining it?

Comment: As a last resort, you can, of course, just list all the sixteen codewords :-)

Comment: Correct. Using PCM like this requires you to construct one. Because the dual code is also cyclis, you can use the result that the dual code is generated by the reciprocal polynomial of $(x^7-1)/g(x)$. That may save a bit of time!

Comment: That what i was think of, but is there any smarter proof? And regarding my answer to (2), is it ok?

Comment: Yes. Your argument for part 2 is correct. My answer seeks to explain why no polynomial of weight two and a low enough degree can have $a$ as a zero. Don't know if its smarter, but it's different.

Comment: Okay, but then it implies that every irreducible polynomial is minimial polynomial of its root, is it true? Im just suprised of this result @Jyrki

Answer (score 1):

A hint for a different route to part 3:

1. Show that the multiplicative order of $a$ is seven. In other words $a^n\neq1$ for all $n$, $0<n<7$.
2. Show that if $f$ is a factor of a **binomial** $g(x)=x^i+x^j$, $i>j$ then $g$ has degree at least $7$.